# PowerPivot for SharePoint 2013 experience

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powerpivot

Does anybody have practical experience with PowerPivot for SharePoint (especially SharePoint 2013) to implement a self-service BI scenario in an on premise environment? 
 Some questions that I’m particular interested in:

• What major problems did you experience during the actual implementation?

• Experience in connection to existing SQL Server Data Warehouses as a PowerPivot data source?

• Authentication of “SSAS server in SharePoint mode” to existing SharePoint 2013 farm

• Resource Load on existing SharePoint application and SQL Server, for example does it make sense to create a dedicated application server for the Excel /PowerPivot service application, for performance / future scalability reasons?

• Hardware suggestion for a dedicated “SSAS server in SharePoint mode” for a total of 1000 PowerPivot users

Thanks